# Google storage bucket is public and still no access to files

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am creating a public bucket with nodeJS (apologise for the ES5/ES6 mix, copied Google's example were ES5):

```
 var gcloud = require('google-cloud');

 const gcs = gcloud.storage({
      projectId: 'h-212f6',
      keyFilename: './h-9a814129651f4.json'
 });

const createBucket = (bucketName) => {
  // Create a new bucket.

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    gcs.createBucket(bucketName, function (err, bucket) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }

        bucket.acl.add({
            entity: 'allUsers',
            role: gcloud.storage.acl.READER_ROLE
        }, function(err, aclObject) {
            console.log('err -> ', err);
        });

        resolve(bucket);
    });

  });
};

const upload = (bucket, filepath, options) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        bucket.upload(filepath, options, function (err, file) {

            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve(file)
        });
    });
};
```

Yet having trouble accessing the file from Chrome:

[image: chrome error]

***UPDATE:***

When I change the file's ACL all seems to work:

```
const upload = (bucket, filepath, options) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        bucket.upload(filepath, options, function (err, file) {

            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            file.acl.add({
                entity: 'allUsers',
                role: gcs.acl.READER_ROLE
            }, function (err, aclObject) {

                console.log('err -> ', err);

            });

            resolve(file)
        });
    });
};
```

However, I was under the assumption that changing the bucket ACL should be enough, isn't it?

Comment: Can you tell us more about where you're running this code? What operation is returning the 401 specifically? Is it possible the relative path on line 5 isn't working right?

Comment: Sure thing. Running it locally and getting the error when trying to navigate from chrome to the returned url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the ACL in your code above, you're setting it for existing objects. In order to set it as the default ACL for new objects, too, you need to do the following:

```
bucket.acl.default.add({
    entity: 'allUsers',
    role: gcloud.storage.acl.READER_ROLE
}, function(err, aclObject) {
    console.log('err -> ', err);
});
```

See [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.2.0/storage) for more examples.